# How to change spacing between nodes that were drawn with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-styles, nodes, graphs

I have a grid of nodes labeled "orthographic layer" whose spacing I would like to modify. There is too much space between the nodes, and I would like it to look more "grid-like". How do I do this? The code is below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
  every neuron/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=1mm
  },
  neuron missing/.style={
    draw=none, 
    scale=5,
    text height=0.333cm,
    execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$
  },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=stealth]

\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,...,5}
  \node [every neuron/.try] (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\y) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,...,5}
  \node [every neuron/.try ] (input2-\m) at (0.25,2.5-\y) {} ;
\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,...,5}
  \node [every neuron/.try] (input3-\m) at (0.5,2.5-\y) {} ;
  \foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,...,5}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (input4-\m) at (0.75,2.5-\y) {} ;
\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (lexical-\m) at (2,2-\y) {};
  
\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,2,3,4}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (semantic-\m) at (4,1.5-\y) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try ] (context-\m) at (6,1.5-\y) {};

\foreach \l [count=\x from 0 ] in {Orthographic, Lexical, Semantic, Contextual}
  \node [align=center, above] at (\x*2,2) {\l \\ layer};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `too much space between the nodes`... please be more specific. Maybe a sketch of what you're looking for would help. A solution could be to play a bit with your `foreach` loops, especially by modifying those `at (0,2.5-\y) {}` with something like `at (0,2-0.3*\y) {}`.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

Your image remains me on table, so it can be write as such. By use of the `makecell` package for writing column headers  and `chains` Ti*k*Z library for positioning nodes in cells (where necessary):

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\tikzset{
node distance = 2pt,
  start chain = going right,
     C/.style = {circle, draw, on chain, node contents={}},
   dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt, node contents={}},
every picture/.append style = {baseline}
        }
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{*4{c}}
 \thead{Orthographic\\ layer}
    &   \thead{Lexical\\ layer}
        &   \thead{Semantic\\ layer}
            &   \thead{Contextual\\ layer}   \\
\tikz{\foreach \i in {1,...,4}\node [C];}
    &   &   &   \\ 
%
    &   \tikz{\node [C];}
        &   &   \\
%
\tikz{\foreach \i in {1,...,4}\node [C];}
    &   \tikz{\node [dot];}
       &    &   \tikz{\node [dot];}   \\
%
    &   \tikz{\node [C];}
        &   &   \\
%
\tikz{\foreach \i in {1,...,4}\node [C];}
    &   &   \tikz{\node [C];}  
            &   \tikz{\node [C];}   \\
%
\tikz{\foreach \i in {1,...,4}\node [C];}
    &   &   \tikz{\node [C];}
            &   \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

*Note*:

- distance between nodes (circles) in cells are controlled by `node distance˙ defined in the` \tikzset`
- vertical distances (in above MWE is used default settings of tables) can be changed by macro `makegapedcells` defined in `makecells` package. For example:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{*4{c}}
% table body
\end{table}
```

- distance between column can be change by `\tabcolsep` which default value is 6pt. It can be changed by `\setlength\tabcolsept{<desired column sep>}`

Comment: Thank you! Eventually I want to connect an arbitrary set of nodes with arrows (as in a neural network). Is this possible with the tabular format?

Comment: @Sam, it is possible, however is not simple/flexible as at pure image (for example by use of the `tikzmark` library). You may consider to use `matrix` environment defined in the `matrix` Ti*k*Z library. Please, make your question more clear, what is your final goal and add some image(sketch what you like to have (in new question, this as is, is seems to be solved).