# tikz - issue filling nodes in foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following tikz picture:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=stealth]

\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,2,missing,3}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try] (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\y) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try] (hidden-\m) at (2,2.2-\y*1.1) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try, fill=black] (output-\m) at (4,1.1-\y) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Image 2]

However, I want to fill the second column of nodes with a color, e.g. black, while still keeping the
`foreach` structure. I tried doing it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=stealth]

\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,2,missing,3}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try] (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\y) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try, fill=black] (hidden-\m) at (2,2.2-\y*1.1) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try, fill=black] (output-\m) at (4,1.1-\y) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, this results in the following. It seems that I falsely fill the missing dots aswell (which I do not want to do, I only want to fill the nodes). Any help is appreciated.

[image: Image 2]

Comment: I think there are some style definitions missing from your example, no circles are visible in it.

Comment: what's `missing`, and `neuron`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you took the code from [How to change spacing between nodes that were drawn with Tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/596842/1952) (at least `neuron style` and `neuron missing` are also declared there) you can force that `neuron missing` include a `fill=none` option and apply a `fill=black` on second foreach, but before `neuron missing` style be applied.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{%
  every neuron/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=1mm
  },
  neuron missing/.style={
    draw=none, 
    scale=5,
    text height=0.333cm,
    execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$,
    fill=none
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm, >=stealth]

\foreach \m/\l [count=\y] in {1,2,missing,3}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try] (input-\m) at (0,2.5-\y) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1,missing,2}
  \node [fill=black, every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try] (hidden-\m) at (2,2.2-\y*1.1) {};

\foreach \m [count=\y] in {1}
  \node [every neuron/.try, neuron \m/.try, fill=black] (output-\m) at (4,1.1-\y) {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did. And thank you.